# How to stringify [object HTMLDivElement] to html string in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have written following code to find and get the `div` element with id `vcr_data` from `html string`. When I try to append that `div` to `html` tag, it's getting printed as follows instead of the stringified `div`:

```
... <body>[object HTMLDivElement]</body></html>
```

code snippet:

```
let doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(html, 'text/html');
console.log('div element ', doc.getElementById('vcr_data'));

const response = `<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <style id="jss-server-side"></style>
    </head>
    <body>${doc.getElementById('vcr_data')}</body>
  </html>`;

console.log('html: ', response);
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `.outerHTML` to get the HTML of the DIV.

```
<body>${doc.getElementById('vcr_data').outerHTML}</body>
```

Comment: And in case anyone's trying to do this with the `Click Element` variable in Google Tag manager like I was: Use the `dataLayer` variable `gtm.element.outerHTML`